# Use the table of grid view generated using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, gridview

I am generating a **grid view** using php and ajax and applying filters using ajax too. Everything is working excellent. But now I want to add a button to generate **CSV**.The **CSV**  should be according to the table displayed when filters are applied or when they are not. 
The first thought I came up with was to use `file_get_contents()` to get source of page but soon I realized that table will not be in source code as it is based on ajax. I am new to ajax. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might help you
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel/

Comment: This was not that helpful I don't  want to put filters in CSV they are in table too.